# SQL setting href to an automated email

Tags: html-email, sql-server-2016

I am sending an automated email from SQL by creating a job which works fine, in that mail I am providing a link to give feedback which I framed as follows

```
DECLARE @Url NVARCHAR(MAX) = '<a href="http://myserver/Feedback" 
target="popup" onclick="window.open(''http://myserver/Feedback'', ''popup'', ''width=600,height=600''); return false;"> Feedback </a>'
```

But when it comes to mail it is always opening in a new tab instead of popup. This is what I seen when I view source of it

```
<a href="http://myserver/Feedback" target="_blank" data-saferedirecturl="https://www.google.com/url?hl=en&amp;q=http://myserver/Feedback&amp;source=gmail&amp;ust=1502263948699000&amp;usg=AFQjCNGmWSvhnQrF8wnbUOqsd2bTuS5u2A"> Feedback </a>
```

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. That SQL code is very product specific.

Comment: Your `@Url` is ok, but opening link in new tab/widnows depends on settings of your browser. In Chrome you can open link in new window using`Shift` + LMB.

Comment: But if the same I manually change by inspecting the element it is opening as popup, so what I need is how should it work so that it should be as popup

Comment: Javascripts dont work on emails so popups will not work. You will have to use `_blank` as the target for all links.